# Zabbix 6 Remote command not available

Tags: zabbix, remotecommand

I am unable to get the remote command option on zabbix 6 for some reason any ideas?[Operation description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bToZb.png)

if anyone can assist me i have worked through all the user manuals and they don't mention something about requirements on this drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 6, commands are available for execution **if previously defined in global scripts** with `Action operation` selected as its scope.

In the previous versions, you just needed to select "remote command" as "operation type".

See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/notifications/action/operation#configuring-an-operation

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix support came back with the answer on this and this is what you need to do.

Please be advised that In Zabbix 6.0 to use Scripts in Operations step you need to create such Scripts in Administration - Scripts section in Zabbix Frontend and set
Scope to Action operation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8TYv.png)
Then this Script will be available in your Operations steps:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxHgf.png)

So basically there is a seprate section to go and create your scripts and assign them to the action you want to take.